# Using prevent default to take over spacebar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code like this to take over the space bar's function:

```
    $(document).keypress(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();                            
        if (e.which == 32) {
            // func
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately this destroys all key's defaults.

This:

```
    $(document).keypress(function (e) { 
        if (e.which == 32) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // func
        }
    });
```

Is unfortunately ineffective.

How can I make it preventDefault of only spacebar?

Thanks.

Comment: The main issue is that you need to watch for keydown with spacebar instead of keyup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
//e= e || window.event); you may need this statement to make sure IE doesn't keep the orginal event in motion
var code;  
if (e.keyCode) {
 code = e.keyCode;
} else if (e.which) {
 code = e.which;
 }
if (code == 32) {
 if (e.stopPropagation) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
 }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: see example in motion:http://www.tedspence.com/index.php?entry=entry070503-103948

Comment: @Jourkey- if you referring to key 192 ` it varies across OS and browser, so check here for some examples: http://74.125.93.132/search?q=cache:swcNVF6ocRMJ:www.openspc2.org/reibun/javascript/appendix/keydown.html+keydown+192&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 3):

For some above things like the use of $ might be confusing a bit. So I am posting my answer with javascript code. Add this in any file to block spacebar (or you can also add other actions) .

```
window.onkeydown = function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 32) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

Keycode 32 is the spacebar. For other keycodes, check this site:

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm

Good luck

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll find that this question was asked, and answered more than four years ago, though...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){<br>
    if(e.which==32) e.preventDefault();<br>
});
```

I use it for blocking Esc key and works fine for me.

Comment: Ah, the mysterious $ function. Reserved for machine generated code by the ECMA spec, but used by half a dozen libraries for different functions in each.

Comment: This works for the spacebar, but doesn't work for 192 `, which in Firefox still pops up a search.