# Prevent space button from triggering any other button click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application where I am using the space bar to toggle a function anywhere in the window. However, if any other button or checkbox has focus, then that gets clicked as well.

I tried preventDefault() but that didn't work out as expected. How can I ensure that no other element on the screen gets clicked when I press the spacebar?

*HTML*

```
<button class="buttons" id="playBtn">PLAY</button>
```

*JS* (Updated according to [Using prevent default to take over spacebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940180/using-prevent-default-to-take-over-spacebar)

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

    if(keycode == '32') {
        if (event.stopPropagation) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        playBtn_DOM.click();
    } else if (keycode == '97') {
        event.preventDefault();
        prevBtn_DOM.click();
    } else if (keycode == '100') {
        event.preventDefault();
        nextBtn_DOM.click();
    }
});
```

And with respect to answer [Using prevent default to take over spacebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940180/using-prevent-default-to-take-over-spacebar), that solution didn't work. I have updated the JS code to show that I tried including the solution given there.

Comment: this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940180/using-prevent-default-to-take-over-spacebar

Comment: I tried preventDefault().
But if another button has focus, that gets clicked as well. No idea why.

Comment: Show some of you code, namely how you bind space bar key?

Comment: @dfsq, I added the code. Do look into it.

The other keypresses, namely 97(A) and 100(D) do not create a problem since they do not have a default binding.

Comment: @Yaakov Ellis, this isn't a duplicate question. Just look into the answer I have updated. I have tried the other solutions on SO and hence posted a new question. Do vote to reopen the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a relatively hacky solution to this. Better answers are most welcome!

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event){
    if (document.activeElement != document.body) document.activeElement.blur();
 });
```

Basically, it checks if mouse is anywhere in document's body. If yes, then it blurs any other element that has focus.

Answer (score 10):

I also had this problem and after a bit of fiddling found that it's `keyup` that triggers button clicks. I've made a fiddle that demonstrates this: https://jsfiddle.net/Beppe/o6gfertu/1/. It works in Firefox and Chrome, although in the latter the button changes appearance to look pressed.

Comment: To expand on this, you'll want to handle both `keypress` and `keyup` and call `event.preventDefault()` in both. The `keypress` event for space acts as page down when nothing has focus (in Chrome anyway). And if a button has focus, it's clicked on `keyup`.

Comment: Great solution. Check the fiddle example to understand what the answers talk's about, I did not understand it just by reading the text.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use

```
$(element).blur();
```

to unfocus any element (like button) when it is focused (like click event for button).

Comment: This worked great.  I had a button that was same toggle as spacebar so spacebar  appeared dead after clicking button as the keyup of spacebar clicked the button.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are expecting SPACE in some text input within clickable DIV. Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="someClickableDiv" onclick="doSomething()">
    <textarea onkeyup="event.preventDefault()"></textarea>
</div>
```

Or Angular 6 version:

```
<div id="someClickableDiv" (click)"doSomething()">
    <textarea (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This will remove focus from all buttons as soon as they are focused (e.g. by a click). This will prevent spacebar from ever activating buttons.

```
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach( function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        this.blur();
    })
})
```